# Run pytest test in main while using fixture

Tags: python, pytest

I am currently using pytest to implement tests for hardware which will perform communication among other things. I am also using the `record_property` fixture to record some values. The test is defined like this:

```py
def test_comm_ytcb_to_ytpb(record_property):
```

To debug this test I would like to run it like follows from within PyCharm:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_comm_ytcb_to_ytpb()
```

Yet, Python will yield the following exception in the console:

```
TypeError: test_comm_ytcb_to_ytpb() missing 1 required positional argument: 'record_property'
```

Of course, the error is justified but what do I need so I can continue debugging just like I did without the `record_property` fixture. I don't mind if nothing is logged or written but I would like to continue debugging the way I did

EDIT:
I just found out that this seems to work:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    def record_property(a, b):
        return

test_comm_ytcb_to_ytpb(record_property)
```

Is that ... acceptable?

Comment: Are you set on needing to run your test as main? Pytest has lots of options for running individual test files/functions. That's how I would approach this.

Comment: If you are using VS Code, I would suggest looking at somekind of plugin for running individual tests in your suite. If you are using some other IDE, I bet there are similar plugins available. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LittleFoxTeam.vscode-python-test-adapter

Comment: @LukeNelson: I am not set on it .. I am just trying how to best debug my tests because it's not some piece of software I am debugging using tests but the tests actually are my software. I'm just using the framework. In the end, I would like to run multiple test sets from the command line (that works already) but I also need to debug the tests themselves.

Comment: @Tzane: I don't mind running them in another tool, yet the issue remains. I do not have a piece of software which is the DUT but actually my tests are what is run. I'm just using the pytest framework for all its goodies (marks, automated logging, ...)